Reference Columns in a Virtual Table in other function
I need to first group by my data by date and then calculate second quartile.
I used the function SUMMARIZE()
But I cannot refer the virtual table column as an argument in the PERCENTILE.INC() and gives below error
`
MyPercntile= 
var tbl_group=SUMMARIZE(site,site[تاريخ],"summm",
CALCULATE(sum(site[حجم معامله به تن]))
)

var bb=PERCENTILE.INC(tbl_group[summm],0.2)
return 
bb

error is
Table variable 'tbl_group' cannot be used in current context because a base table is expected.
What should be done for functions that only have to pass columns?

Is this no longer solved?

Use the iterator function instead (with an X on the end).
PERCENTILEX.EXC
https://dax.guide/percentilex-exc/
